# How to write an XQuery flwor expression to calculate the probability between words?

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I'm writing an XQuery flwor expression to return all the occurrences of the target word 'we' in the xml file, together with the word which comes next in the sentence in each case. I want to calculate the probability as the ratio: (number of times successor word appears after target word 'we' divided by the number of times successor word appears overall).

Here is the XML file I am working on:

```
<u who="PS6H7">
<s n="3">
    <w c5="AV0" hw="well" pos="ADV">Well</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="AJ0" hw="good" pos="ADJ">good </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="afternoon" pos="SUBST">afternoon</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNI" hw="everybody" pos="PRON">everybody</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
    <w c5="VVB" hw="think" pos="VERB">think </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
    <w c5="VHD" hw="have" pos="VERB">'d </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="well" pos="ADV">better </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="get" pos="VERB">get </w>
    <w c5="VVN" hw="start" pos="VERB">started</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="4">
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">We </w>
    <w c5="VVD" hw="look" pos="VERB">looked </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="so" pos="ADV">so </w>
    <w c5="AJ0" hw="thin" pos="ADJ">thin </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="on" pos="PREP">on </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="ground" pos="SUBST">ground</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="i" pos="PRON">I </w>
    <w c5="VVD" hw="think" pos="VERB">thought </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
    <w c5="VM0" hw="would" pos="VERB">'d </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="sit" pos="VERB">sit </w>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="wait" pos="VERB">wait </w>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="see" pos="VERB">see </w>
    <w c5="CJS" hw="if" pos="CONJ">if </w>
    <w c5="PNI" hw="everyone" pos="PRON">everyone</w>
    <w c5="VBZ" hw="be" pos="VERB">'s </w>
    <w c5="VVG-AJ0" hw="come" pos="VERB">coming</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="but" pos="CONJ">but </w>
    <w c5="UNC" hw="erm" pos="UNC">erm </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we</w>
    <w c5="VM0" hw="will" pos="VERB">'ll </w>
    <w c5="VHI" hw="have" pos="VERB">have </w>
    <w c5="TO0" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="get" pos="VERB">get </w>
    <w c5="VVN" hw="start" pos="VERB">started </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="anyway" pos="ADV">anyway</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="5">
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">We</w>
    <w c5="VM0" hw="will" pos="VERB">'ll </w>
    <w c5="VVI" hw="welcome" pos="VERB">welcome</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we </w>
    <w c5="VHB" hw="have" pos="VERB">have </w>
    <w c5="CRD" hw="two" pos="ADJ">two </w>
    <w c5="NN2" hw="speaker" pos="SUBST">speakers</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="mr" pos="SUBST">Mr </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="bob" pos="SUBST">Bob </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="plumtree" pos="SUBST">Plumtree</w>
    <c c5="PUN">, </c>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="ms" pos="SUBST">Ms </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="erica" pos="SUBST">Erica </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="ison" pos="SUBST">Ison</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="6">
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">We </w>
    <w c5="VVD" hw="ask" pos="VERB">asked </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="they" pos="PRON">them </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="meeting" pos="SUBST">meeting </w>
    <w c5="CJC" hw="and" pos="CONJ">and </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="we" pos="PRON">we </w>
    <w c5="VVB" hw="look" pos="VERB">look </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="forward" pos="ADV">forward </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="VVG-NN1" hw="listen" pos="VERB">listening </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="PNP" hw="you" pos="PRON">you </w>
    <w c5="AV0" hw="later" pos="ADV">later </w>
    <w c5="AVP" hw="on" pos="ADV">on </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="in" pos="PREP">in </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="agenda" pos="SUBST">agenda</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="7">
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">The </w>
    <w c5="NN2" hw="minute" pos="SUBST">minutes </w>
    <w c5="PRF" hw="of" pos="PREP">of </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN1" hw="meeting" pos="SUBST">meeting </w>
    <w c5="VVD-VVN" hw="hold" pos="VERB">held </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="in" pos="PREP">in </w>
    <w c5="NP0" hw="january" pos="SUBST">January</w>
    <c c5="PUN">.</c>
</s>

<s n="8">
    <w c5="DT0" hw="any" pos="ADJ">Any </w>
    <w c5="NN2" hw="correction" pos="SUBST">corrections </w>
    <w c5="PRP" hw="to" pos="PREP">to </w>
    <w c5="AT0" hw="the" pos="ART">the </w>
    <w c5="NN2" hw="minute" pos="SUBST">minutes </w>
    <w c5="ORD" hw="first" pos="ADJ">first</w>
    <c c5="PUN">?</c>
</s>

</u>
```

This is my XQuery expression. It returns all the occurrences of the target word 'we, together with the word that comes after it. I am also able to find the frequency (number of times the successor word occurs after target word), but I cannot calculate the probability ratio. The formula to find probability is  (number of times successor word appears after target word 'we' divided by the number of times successor word appears overall).

In result, I want to an HTML table to show the target word 'we' in 1st column, the word that occurs after 'we' in 2nd column and the frequency or number of times the combination occurred in 3rd column, and the probability in the 4th column.

```
<html>
<body>
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>Target</td><td>Successor</td><td>Frequency</td><td>Probability</td></tr>

{

let $target := "we"

let $x := doc("KS0.xml")//u//s//w[lower-case(normalize-space()) = $target]

for $successor in distinct-values($x/following-sibling::w[1])

let $probability := count(doc("KS0.xml")//u//s//w)

let $frequency := $x/following-sibling::w[1][. = $successor]

order by count($frequency) descending

return <tr>
           <td>{$target}</td>
           <td>{$successor}</td>
           <td>{count($frequency)}</td>
           <td>{$probability}</td>
       </tr>
}

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my output which I get. The probability it counts in the 4th column in not correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>Target</td>
            <td>Successor</td>
            <td>Frequency</td>
            <td>Probability</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>'re </td>
            <td>44</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>'ve </td>
            <td>38</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>'ll </td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>have </td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>could </td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>have</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>do </td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>are </td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>'d </td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>do</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>were </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>should </td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>see </td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>will </td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>going </td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>had </td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>shall </td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>can </td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>look </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>did</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>know </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>need </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>make </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>would </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>want </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>hope </td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>looked </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>asked </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>erm </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>talking </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>Chris</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>aiming </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>on</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>come </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>occasionally </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>should</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>ought </td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>we</td>
            <td>said</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>11674</td>
         </tr>

      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're counting *all* words, and not only occurrences of `$target` (and miss the division to actually get the probability). I renamed `$x` on the go when I had to think about what it actually means, better always use speaking variable names (a few additional bytes aren't expensive any more these days). Finally, I replaced the `descendant-or-self` axis steps `//` through `child` steps `/`, which have much lower performance penalty (and the document does not let me assume you really need those).

```
(: snip :)
let $target := "we"
let $occurrences := doc("KS0.xml")/u/s/w[lower-case(normalize-space()) = $target]
for $successor in distinct-values($occurrences/following-sibling::w[1])
let $frequency := $occurrences/following-sibling::w[1][. = $successor]
let $probability := count($frequency) div count(/u/s/w[lower-case(normalize-space()) = lower-case(normalize-space($successor))])
order by count($frequency) descending
return <tr>
           <td>{$target}</td>
           <td>{$successor}</td>
           <td>{count($frequency)}</td>
           <td>{$probability}</td>
       </tr>
(: snip :)
```

Comment: I just realized I didn't match your requirements and slightly edited the calculation of `$probability`.

Comment: You are actually dividing frequency by the total number of time the target word 'we' occurred. I want to find the probability by dividing the frequency by the total number of time the successor word occured.

Comment: I already realized this shortly after posting my answer -- it seems you didn't pick up my edit and comment I posted. I think I'm doing exactly what you're aiming at now.

Comment: Follow-up question don't fit the Stack Overflow model. Anyway, look for "positional predicates".