# Problem with counters in XQuery collections

Tags: xquery

I am learning XQuery and came across this code from 5 years ago:

[How to write an XQuery flwor expression to calculate the probability between words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860559/how-to-write-an-xquery-flwor-expression-to-calculate-the-probability-between-wor)

I am learning how to adapt collection() to it and modified the code as follows:

```
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>Target</td><td>Successor</td><td>Frequency</td><td>Probability</td></tr>
{
let $target := "we"
let $occurrences := collection(".?select=*xml")//s//w[lower-case(normalize-space())=$target]
for $successor in distinct-values($occurrences/following-sibling::w[1])
let $frequency := $occurrences/following-sibling::w[1][. = $successor]

let $probability := count($frequency) div count(collection(".?select=*xml")//s//w[lower-case(normalize-space()) = lower-case(normalize-space($successor))])

order by count($frequency) descending
return <tr>
           <td>{$target}</td>
           <td>{$successor}</td>
           <td>{count($frequency)}</td>
           <td>{$probability}</td>
       </tr>
}
</table>
</body>
```

While it works well, as in giving a desired result, it's terribly inefficient and takes a long time! I know it is because of second collection occurring. My question is, could you please give me suggestion on how to rewrite the part where second collection happens? The goal is to collect all the words that are of same value as $occurrences/following-sibling::w[1] (but not necessarily coming after $target, I need to find all words of same value as sibling to use it as dividend) without using second collection.

Comment: Which XQuery processor or implementation do you use, which XQuery version is supported?

Answer (score 0):

In an XML database like BaseX you should try to set up indexes on `w`, in general grouping could help:

```
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>Target</td><td>Successor</td><td>Frequency</td><td>Probability</td></tr>
{
let $target := "we"
let $occurrences := collection(".?select=*xml")//s//w[lower-case(normalize-space())=$target]
for $successor in $occurrences/following-sibling::w[1]
group by $w := lower-case(normalize-space($sucessor))
let $frequency := count($successor)

let $probability := $frequency div count(collection(".?select=*xml")//s//w[lower-case(normalize-space()) = $w])

order by $frequency descending
return <tr>
           <td>{$target}</td>
           <td>{$w}</td>
           <td>{$frequency}</td>
           <td>{$probability}</td>
       </tr>
}
</table>
</body>
```

Depending on the implementation of collection and/or the optimizer it might or might not help to pull `let $words := collection(".?select=*xml")//s//w` into a variable and use it further on:

```
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>Target</td><td>Successor</td><td>Frequency</td><td>Probability</td></tr>
{
let $target := "we",
    $words := collection(".?select=*xml")//s//w
let $occurrences := $words[lower-case(normalize-space())=$target]
for $successor in $occurrences/following-sibling::w[1]
group by $w := lower-case(normalize-space($sucessor))
let $frequency := count($successor)

let $probability := $frequency div count($words[lower-case(normalize-space()) = $w])

order by $frequency descending
return <tr>
           <td>{$target}</td>
           <td>{$w}</td>
           <td>{$frequency}</td>
           <td>{$probability}</td>
       </tr>
}
</table>
</body>
```

I don't the volume of the collections and the number of words you have but as you want to find and count certain words it might also help to count all first in a map and then just to access the map e.g.

```
<table border='1'>
<tr><td>Target</td><td>Successor</td><td>Frequency</td><td>Probability</td></tr>
{
let $target := "we",
    $words := collection(".?select=*xml")//s//w,
    $word-map := map:merge(for $word in $words group by $key := lower-case(normalize-space($word)) return map { $key : count($word) })
let $occurrences := $words[lower-case(normalize-space())=$target]
for $successor in $occurrences/following-sibling::w[1]
group by $w := lower-case(normalize-space($sucessor))
let $frequency := count($successor)

let $probability := $frequency div $word-map($w)

order by $frequency descending
return <tr>
           <td>{$target}</td>
           <td>{$w}</td>
           <td>{$frequency}</td>
           <td>{$probability}</td>
       </tr>
}
</table>
</body>
```

It would also be interesting to see whether using XQuery 3.1 windowing helps but I would need to see the structure of the XML first.